# Check if SpatiaLite database is open - android

Tags: android, jsqlite

I am trying to check if my jsqlite database is open or not. Unfortunately there is not an isOpen() function for this kind of database and I can't find any similar method to check if the database is open or not. Has anyone faced this problem before? I can't find any reference in documentation.

Comment: Please, undelete your last question (about colors on XML) and check my answer as the correct one, giving me my deserved reputation points and respecting my integrity and my time and efforts in your benefit. I will +1 you for it. Thank you. God bless.